# Counting comparisons and exchanges in my Shell sort program

Tags: java, shellsort

I'm trying to count the comparisons and exchanges it take for Shell sort to sort an array of numbers `int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`. With the comparison counter where it is now (`comp`) and the exchange counter where it is (`exch`) I'm getting 22 comparisons and zero exchanges. I believe the zero exchanges is right because its obviously a sorted array so no exchanges are needed. With an array of 10 elements I don't think 22 comparisons would be correct. Can someone show me where these expressions need to be and explain why? I would greatly appreciate it.

```java
public static void shellSort(int[] array) {
    int interval = array.length / 2;
    int comp = 0, exch = 0;
    while (interval != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < interval; i++) {
            for (int p = i + interval; p < array.length; p += interval) {
                int key = array[p];
                int j = p - interval;
                while (j >= 0) {
                    comp++;         //Comparison here
                    if (key < array[j]) {
                        array[j + interval] = array[j];
                    } else
                        break;
                    exch++;     //Exchange here
                    j -= interval;
                }
                array[j + interval] = key;
            }
        }
        interval /= 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort#Description):

`{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`

1. With gap `5` (`10 >>> 1`):

   ```
   {1,6}{2,7}{3,8}{4,9}{5,10}
     ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    --> 5 comparisons
   ```
2. With gap `2` (`5 >>> 1`):

   ```
   {1,3,5,7,9}{2,4,6,8,10}
     ^ ^ ^ ^    ^ ^ ^ ^    --> 8 comparisons
   ```
3. With gap `1` (`2 >>> 1`):

   ```
   {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
     ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^    --> 9 comparisons
   ```

Total: 22 comparisons. Where's the problem? :)

**UPDATE**

`10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1`

1. With gap `5` (`10 >>> 1`):

   ```
   10,5  9,4  8,3  7,2  6,1
     ê    ê    ê    ê    ê  --> 5c, 5e
   ```

`5,4,3,2,1,10,9,8,7,6`

2. With gap `2` (`5 >>> 1`):

   ```
   5,3,1,9,7

   5,3 
    ê        --> 1c, 1e --> 3,4,5,2,1,10,9,8,7,6
   3,5,1                    ‾   ‾
    ê ê      --> 2c, 2e --> 1,4,3,2,5,10,9,8,7,6
   1,3,5,9                  ‾   ‾   ‾
        ^    --> 1c
   1,3,5,9,7
        ^ ê  --> 2c, 1e --> 1,4,3,2,5,10,7,8,9,6
                                         ‾   ‾   
   4,2,10,8,6

   4,2
    ê         --> 1c, 1e --> 1,2,3,4,5,10,7,8,9,6
   2,4,10                      ‾   ‾
      ^       --> 1c
   2,4,10,8
      ^  ê    --> 2c, 1e --> 1,2,3,4,5,8,7,10,9,6
   2,4,8,10,6                          ‾   ‾‾
      ^ ê  ê  --> 3c, 2e --> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
                                       ‾   ‾   ‾‾
   ```
3. With gap `1` (`2 >>> 1`):

   ```
   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
    ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^   --> 9c
   ```

I come to a total of 27 comparisons and 13 exchanges.

I'm pretty sure you're able to perform the last pen-and-paper test on your own now. :)

Comment: so can you give me a hint on how to fix it so the comparisons and exchanges are correct?

Comment: @dantheDude I'm terribly sorry. I made a mistake. Under 2. I calculated row-wise but it has to be column-wise (=one sub-array after the other). I adapted my answer accordingly.